# How to hook a code to form submit on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I'm a newbie to wordpress plugin development and from the wordpress development tutorials and articles I've come to understand that in order to add a kind of a listener to an action, hooks must be used. So can anyone tell me how to do such thing on form submit? Suppose there's another plugin handling the form creation if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plugin that is generating the form has created any hooks that can be hooked in to you should be able to do that and add your own custom code.

Alternatively I think you can use the admin post hook. Basically you do something like the following:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_add_foobar', 'prefix_admin_add_foobar' );

function prefix_admin_add_foobar() {
    // Handle request then generate response using echo or leaving PHP and using HTML
}
```

So the above goes into your functions.php file, and whenever your form has an action parameter of 'add_foorbar', the code within the 'prefix_admin_add_footbar' function is called. This code is taken directly from https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action) which should provide more info.

Comment: This only works when a logged in user submits the form. There is an admin_post_nopriv_.. hook that fires when a not logged in user submits the form. If you want to allow both, you have to use both hooks. See example on the admin_post_action manual page.