# Wordpress - Hook on submit form

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

On a page managed by each customer of my Wordpress website, I have a form with multiple fields, not only Wordpress core fields, but also WooCommerce fields, JetEngine fields, etc.

I need to update the user data on another app, via API. I can't find a hook where I can plug my own function, hook fired when all other hook are processed. Because if I hook profile_update, for example, the updated_user_meta calls have not been made, and all the data are not updated yet.

So my thought led me to find a hook which is fired when the form is submit. This way I will be able to get the form fields in my function (called with add_action) and then launch my API calls.

The problem is I can't find a hook which is fired on form submit. Do you have any idea of how I can manage that?

Thanks for your help!

PS: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868144/how-to-hook-a-code-to-form-submit-on-wordpress) is not helping, because it's about admin form, and I'm not on admin side but on customer side, on his profile form.

Comment: _"Because if I hook profile_update, for example, the updated_user_meta calls have not been made, and all the data are not updated yet."_ - but you get the data passed into the hook callback function - so why not use _that_ as the source for your API calls then?

Comment: You are right, I have the new data in the `$userdata` argument (the third one) of the hook callback function of `profile_update`.

But I only have data for the profile_update. Not, for example, the WooCommerce address, or the meta field from JetEngine :-(

Comment: `woocommerce_customer_save_address` and similar also exist, and JetEngine probably provides hooks around the parts where it is processing its data, I would assume. Or you could just work with the raw data as it arrives in $_POST, assuming you can determine what belongs where.

Comment: I know that a lot of hooks exists... but if I make one API call for each hooks that is updated my user: 1/ I will have to find all the hooks one by one ; 2/ I will have a lot of calls to my API, sometime to update only one field. I don't really like this approach, but I can't find a better one for now.

Using $_POST is another solution you are right... but I will maybe have incorrect data :-(

Comment: You could gather the data inside the individual hooks, put it into the session or a global variable (eww ...) - and then make one API call with that, in one "final" hook that executes very late.

Comment: Or maybe you de-couple this from the actual update - and use a cron instead, that regularly checks which users had their properties updated since the last run, and then make the API calls for those. (I don't know if WP records any sort of "last modified" timestamp, but if not you could implement that yourself, by setting a custom meta value inside profile_update or something.)

Comment: Yup, that's some ideas, you are right. I have excluded the cron solution because if there is a lot of updates to make, it will become long to make API calls (and background jobs are not really Wordpress feature :') ), but I will think about all of this !

Thanks !

Comment: _"and background jobs are not really Wordpress feature"_ - well, it has the "WP Cron" feature - normally that only gets triggered by a page load, but you can also implement it as a _regular_ cron on the server level - https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/

Comment: Yes, know all that ! Thanks a lot for your help :-)